# Extract values from a string that follow a specific word using sed

Tags: sed, filter

I'd like to extract only a specific value from command output.

The string that the command returns is something like this:

```
Result: " 5 Secs (11.2345%) 60 Secs (22.3456%) 300 Secs (33.4567%)"
```

And I want to filter only the "60 Secs" value between ()

```
22.3456%
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried? From what is stated in your question, it looks like you actually want to return what's between `()` after `5 Secs`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If that is the exact string that the command returns, then `sed` will work.

```
command_output | sed 's/.*60 Secs..\(.*\)..300.*/\1/'
```

That prints everything between `60 Secs (` and `) 300`.

Result:

```
22.3456%
```

Comment: so close.. almost perfect..  it return an extra ) after %

Comment: @Tracobetti I can't reproduce that.  It looks like you are missing one of the `.` before `300`. One of them represents the `)` and the other represents the space.

Comment: ok. got it. before 300 there are ) plus 2 space. with 3 dot it works.   |  sed 's/.*60 Secs..\(.*\)...300.*/\1/'

Comment: exactly. you got it

Comment: @Tracobetti What I meant is that it has one space.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it in `sed`, yes. Just search for `60 Secs (` and then as many non`-%` characters as possible until the first `%`:

```
$ echo "5 Secs (11.2345%) 60 Secs (22.3456%) 300 Secs (33.4567%)" | 
    sed 's/.* 60 Secs (\([^%]*%\).*/\1/'
22.3456%
```

Or, in perl:

```
$ echo "5 Secs (11.2345%) 60 Secs (22.3456%) 300 Secs (33.4567%)" | 
    perl -lne '/.* 60 Secs \(([^%]*%)/; print "$1"'
22.3456%
```

Or, if the format is standard and you know you always want the 6th field, you can do:

```
$ echo "5 Secs (11.2345%) 60 Secs (22.3456%) 300 Secs (33.4567%)" | 
    awk '{gsub(/[()]/,""); print $6}'
22.3456%
```

or:

```
$ echo "5 Secs (11.2345%) 60 Secs (22.3456%) 300 Secs (33.4567%)" | 
    cut -d' ' -f6 | tr -d '()'
22.3456%
```

Comment: Is the space necessary in `.* 60`?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity yes, I don't want to match `360 Secs`, for example. The space makes sure I only match `60` and not other things that include `60`.

Comment: Right! I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: As it usually happens, it snapped to me last night before sleeping  the following: if the string *starts* with "60 seconds" as in `60 Secs (22.3456%) ...` some of your solutions will fail leaving the blank before "60".

Comment: Would be this a solution? `sed 's/.*[[:blank:]]*60 Secs (\([^%]*%\).*/\1/'`?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity yes, all the solutions here except the final awk one assume that the `60` isn't at the very beginning of the file. But no, the `.*[[:blank:]]*60` won't do either because `.*[[:blank:]]*` will also match anything at all since the `*` means "0 or more". You would need something more complicated like `/(^| )60 Secs/` to allow aither a space or the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 3):

You can use GNU `grep` instead of `sed`:

```bsh
$ foo='Result: "5 Secs (11.2345%) 60 Secs (22.3456%) 300 Secs (33.4567%)"'
$ echo "$foo" | grep -Po "(?<= 60 Secs \()[0-9\.%]*"
22.3456%
```

And with `sed`:

```bsh
$ echo "$foo" | sed 's/^.* 60 Secs (\([0-9\.%]*\).*$/\1/'
22.3456%
```

Both commands capture the string with `0-9.%` characters after "60 secs (".

With `awk`:

```bsh
$ echo "$foo" | awk -F'[() ]' '{ print $10 }'
22.3456%
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `grep -P`'s `\K` to reset the start of the match:

```bsh
$ echo "$result" | grep -Po '60 Secs \(\K[^)]*'
22.3456%
```